# Sum of derivatives of christoffels, vector laplacian on basis

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

One can define the connection laplacian on $TM$ as
$$
\Delta X := \sum_i \nabla_i \nabla_i X - \nabla_{\nabla_i \partial_i} X
$$

where $\{\partial_i\}$ give an orthonormal basis at a point, induce by coordinates. If we further assume these are parallel (e.g. geodesic normal coordinates), then
$$
\Delta X := \sum_i \nabla_i \nabla_i X = \sum_i X^k_{ii} \partial_k + X^k \nabla_i \nabla_i \partial_k
$$
Is there a name or reduction for the connection laplacian on basis elements, e.g. $V_k := \sum_i \nabla_i \nabla_i \partial_k$? In terms of christoffels, we can write
$$
V_k = \sum_i \nabla_i \nabla_i \partial_k = (\sum_i \Gamma_{ik,i}^j) \partial_j
$$
So equivalently, can this sum of derivatives of christoffels be reduced in general?

Comment: I guess no. That term is not invariant under coordinates, so it might not be well-defined.

Comment: @ArcticChar sorry, what about if I framed a (1,1) tensor 

$$ T^j_k := g^{mn} \Gamma^j_{mk,n}$$

is this not well defined independent of coordinates? Maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: The Christoffel symbols are not invariant under coordinates. I am not sure about the expression in your comments. (That said, the Christoffel symbols does have a name....)

Comment: Ah, fair point! Yes maybe just looking for name, not invariance. Thanks for your thoughts